# Automapper and complex object

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a complex object that I need to translate on a List of simple DTO object.

My map is this:

```
CreateMap<ObjASource, IEnumerable<MyDto>>()
            .ConvertUsing(source => source.ObjB?.ObjC?.Select(p => new MyDto
            {
                field1 = source.field1,
                field2 = source.field2,
                field3 = source.field3,
                field4 = p.fieldX,
                field5 = p.fieldY
            }).ToList()
            );
```

This map works good when I'm working with singol ObjA 
 like this`mapper.Map<IList<MyDto>>(my_singol_objA);` but doesn't work when I'm working with a list of ObjA `mapper.Map<IList<MyDto>>(my_list_of_objA);`

I don't know which other kind of map I have to add to correct this.

Thanks guys

**EDITED because I didn't solve**

I want to explain better and in more simple way my problems, maybe someone can help me. 
I have a complex object with inside a Collection.

An object like this:

```
public class Product { 
    int product_id {get; set;}; 
    string name {get; set;}; 
    List<CompaniesProvideProduct> company  {get; } 
}
```

The CompaniesProvideProduct contains the relation with a company that sell the product and have more details.

```
public class CompaniesProvideProduct { 
    int product_id {get; set;}; 
    int company_id {get; set;}; 
    decimal price {get; set;}; 

}
```

Then the destination object of my translation is:

```
public class ProductDto { 
    int product_id {get; set;}; 
    string name {get; set;}; 
    int company_id {get; set;}; 
    decimal price {get; set;}; 

}
```

In my program I get from db a List and I want to translate this object in a List. For 1 record of Product I'll have more record of ProductDto.

I tried with:

```
CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>(); //to get product_id and name
CreateMap<CompaniesProvideProduct, ProductDto>(); //to get company_id and price

CreateMap<Product, IEnumerable<ProductDto>>()
.ConvertUsing<ProductConverter>();

public class ProductConverter : ITypeConverter<Product, IEnumerable<ProductDto>>
{

    IEnumerable<ProductDto> ITypeConverter<Product, IEnumerable<ProductDto>>.Convert(Product source, IEnumerable<ProductDto> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        Product prod = source;
        foreach (var dto in prod.company.Select(e => context.Mapper.Map<ProductDto>(e)))
        {
            context.Mapper.Map(prod, dto);
            yield return dto;
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work for me. If someone can help me I'll be very happy.

Thanks.

Comment: Collections are handled by default, there is no need for a map for them.

Comment: Thank you @LucianBargaoanu I knew this but my mapping is not correct and I receive error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lucian is correct. Collections are handled by default. So if your original mapping is setup correctly `object => list<object>` then `list<object> => list<list<object>>` would work as well.

```
           expression.CreateMap<ObjASource, List<MyDto>>()
                .ConvertUsing(source =>
                    {
                        return source.ObjB?.ObjC?.Select(p => new MyDto
                        {
                            field1 = source.field1,
                            field2 = source.field2,
                            field3 = source.field3,
                            field4 = p.fieldX,
                            field5 = p.fieldY
                        })
                        .ToList();
                    }
            );
```

Here's the working sample:

```
        var test = new List<ObjASource>
        {
            new ObjASource
            {
                field1 = "1",
                field2 = "2",
                field3 = "3",
                ObjB = new ObjB
                {
                    ObjC = new List<ObjC>
                    {
                        new ObjC
                        {
                            fieldX = "X",
                            fieldY = "Y"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var result = Mapper.Map<List<List<MyDto>>>(test);
```

**UPDATE**

So based on your updated question I think I better understand your issue.  Basically you need 2 explicit mappings - `object => List<object>` AND `List<object> => List<object>` - because as explained earlier AutoMapper gives List of List of the object which you do not want:

```
        var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(exp =>
        {
            exp.CreateMap<List<Product>, List<ProductDto>>()
                .ConstructUsing(products => products.SelectMany(product => product.company,
                    (product, companiesProvideProduct) => new ProductDto
                    {
                        product_id = product.product_id,
                        name = product.name,
                        company_id = companiesProvideProduct.company_id,
                        price = companiesProvideProduct.price
                    }).ToList());

            exp.CreateMap<Product, List<ProductDto>>()
                .ConvertUsing(product => product.company.Select(provideProduct => new ProductDto
                {
                    product_id = product.product_id,
                    name = product.name,
                    company_id = provideProduct.company_id,
                    price = provideProduct.price
                }).ToList());
        }).CreateMapper();
```

So then if your object initialization looked like the following:

```
        var productList = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product
            {
                product_id = 1,
                name = "test1",
                company = new List<CompaniesProvideProduct>
                {
                    new CompaniesProvideProduct
                    {
                        company_id = 1,
                        price = 1.99m,
                        product_id = 1
                    }
                }
            },
            new Product
            {
                product_id = 2,
                name = "test2",
                company = new List<CompaniesProvideProduct>
                {
                    new CompaniesProvideProduct
                    {
                        company_id = 2,
                        price = 1.99m,
                        product_id = 2
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

The mapped objects would be:

```
var result1 = mapper.Map<List<ProductDto>>(productList);
var result2 = mapper.Map<List<ProductDto>>(productList.First());
```

Comment: Thank you ODawg, my mapping works if I translate like you wrote. But the problem is that I don't want a Collection of another Collection. I want only one Collection. My ObjB inherits from ObjA and he has more details, ObjC is a relation from ObjB and another class, For this I have a collection of ObjC. I want that my translation give me a Collection of ObjB object with details of relation that I have inside ObjC. I don't know if my explanation is clear.